# Locale based week number prefix when using slotLabelFormat in fullcalendar 3.9.0 with secheduler addon

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, locale, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-3

If using slotLabelFormat you wont get automatic translation for week prefix.

when setting weekNumbers: true you get week numbers displayed with prefix that is locale dependent.

[image: image showing locale based week number prefix]

But if i want to format for example the day row only, the week row disappears so i have to add that in the slotLabelFormat array myself, and then i wont get locale based week number prefix.

```
slotLabelFormat: [
    'w',
    'ddd M/D'
]
```

As seen in picture below the day is now formatted correctly. But the week row only has the number. Of course i could write a prefix with '[w]w'. But that would display a w instead of the correct prefix for chosen locale.

[image]

Is there any way to write the format string so that it uses current locales week number prefix?